# Excel Formula to autopopulate a cell and mark as Assigned

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am attempting to auto populate a excel cell with an account number with the following formula.

```
=INDEX(C2:C20001,MATCH(FALSE,B2:B20001,0))
```

Column B contains True/False and Column C contains the Account Numbers.

```
Assigned  |  Account Number
  True    |  ABC123456789
  False   |  ABC123456790
```

what I am needing is that when an account number is selected by the index/match to then change the value of the assigned from false to true.

The formula I have attempted to use is `=IF(C2=AutoAssignNr,TRUE,FALSE)`   ((AutoAssignNr is the NamedRange of the output of the first formula. ))
this gives me a circular reference error and produces the value of 0.

Could anyone suggest how to resolve this or if there is a better method?

Comment: This won't work because of the circular reference. The only way would be to have an extra column (you can hide it if needed) which does the update for you. But as soon as you change your column B from false to true this would mean, that your previous formular would change again (as it doesn't match anymore) what would result in a circular reference -> thats why you receive that errormessage ;)